# aspect ratio div inside another aspect ratio div not working as intended

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

What is wrong with my code, please? Why is the inner div(two) fill the outer div instead of keeping its aspect ratio by `padding-bottom`?

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  background: #990000;
  background-size: contain;
}

.one:before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
}

.one:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.two {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background: #009900;
}

.two:before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.two:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mhk99j8z/

Comment: Thanks Pete for adding the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't clear your `one:before` float - your `one:after` comes after two - `:after` appends at the end of an element (after all other elements)

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  background: #990000;
  background-size: contain;
}

.one:before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
}
    
.two {
  clear:left;             /* remove one:after and clear on two */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background: #009900;
}

.two:before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.two:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again Pete, but why the second div is on the bottom?

Comment: That's because you used a before for your ratio for one, if you want the red at the bottom, put the padding directly on `one` - not in a pseduo element

Comment: Hm, so it kind of pushing the content down... Alright. So there's no way around it, so the inner div will sit nicely at the top? Because I change the :before for the :after, it does go to the top, but the rest of the div(one) is not showing

Comment: If I put it directly on one, then it will cause other problems :) That was the whole idea - to use pseudo. But I think there's no workaround of this with pseudo, isn't? Thanks anyway Pete. Much appreciate!

Comment: Ah sorry, got called into a meeting. I guess if you want it after, you can just create an empty span and style it (https://jsfiddle.net/mpv9brz6/), unfortunately as it needs to be cleared and you use the after for clearing, you cannot create a clear and a padder both after the second div.